# Dynamically build query in Room

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-room

**Question**

Is it possible to dynamically build the filtering for a query?

**The problem**

I have a big list, addresses. The user can filter it with typing text in a SearchView. If the user put any space in the text it will be divided and the two part of the text will be searched separately. I have to build the SQL dynamically because I didn't know how many space characters will be. Is there any way to handle this in Room whit simple @Query or I have to use @RawQuery for this?

**Example SQL** for this:

```
SELECT * FROM ADDRESS WHERE (CITY LIKE '%abc%' OR STREET LIKE '%abc%') AND (CITY LIKE '%abc%' OR STREET LIKE '%def%') AND (....)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you should do is use [RawQuery](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RawQuery).

Since your query is complicated and you are not sure how long it is, you should probably construct it in runtime and execute it as well.
Room check the validity of the @Query in compile time so I think you'll have a hard time to implement it that way.

This example is taken from the documentation:

```
@Dao
interface RawDao {
 @RawQuery
 User getUserViaQuery(SupportSQLiteQuery query);
}
 SimpleSQLiteQuery query = new SimpleSQLiteQuery("SELECT * FROM User WHERE id = ?   LIMIT 1", new Object[]{userId});
 User user2 = rawDao.getUserViaQuery(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass those words in an array

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM ADDRESS WHERE CITY LIKE(:keywords)") //customize your query here
List addresses(String[] keywords);
```